# ubuntu , how to check how many cd drives are attached to computer

Tags: ubuntu, optical-drive

How can i check which cd drives are attched to computer and is ubuntu detecting them or not

i have seen that there were few drives which werenot showing on the computer but when i mouted them then it shows

but i used gparted to see their `/dev/sda1` address.

but how can i check the cd drives so that i can mount them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of `/dev/sr*` will tell you optical drives were found. Check `/sys/class/block/sr*/device/model` to find out which device is which drive name.